# InnoDB restore database is very slow

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have Mysql installed version 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 (with default InnoDB without any modification)

When using InnoDB, the mysqldump and read performance is comparable to MyISAM, but restore database is very slow.

When trying to install Drupal on blank database also take too long

Other than `default-storage-engine = innodb`, Is there anything I need to do before use InnoDB?

Comment: "Is there anything I need to do before use InnoDB?"  Uh, have you configured _any_ of the MySQL settings?  There are a lot of settings you have to change...  The absolute basics can be found in a set of good posts on [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/).  InnoDB performance tuning is not nearly as straightforward as MyISAM performance tuning:  it's a far more complex storage engine.

Comment: I'm investigating it right now too. I believe it has something to do with excess amounts of fsync syscall while restoring the data.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should disable keys on the tables while restoring. This is the default behavior with the dumps generated from mysqldump. What is the command line you are using for dumping data?
2. You should dump the tables in the order of the primary key.